# JQuery - how do I make the cells in my table one set width and height?

Tags: jquery

Every time I run the program the cells in the table vary in size depending on what letter is in it. I have fiddled around with the CSS but no luck, can anyone help?

```
 var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man", "pin", "gag", "sat", "pat", "tap", "sap", "tag", "gig", "gap", "nag", "sag", "gas", "pig", "dig", "got", "not", "top", "pop", "god", "mog", "cot", "cop", "cap", "cod", "kid", "kit", "get", "pet", "ten", "net", "pen", "peg", "met", "men", "mum", "run", "mug", "cup", "sun", "mud", "rim", "ram", "rat", "rip", "rag", "rug", "rot", "dad", "sad", "dim", "dip", "did", "mam", "map", "nip", "tin", "tan", "nap", "sit", "tip", "pip", "sip", "had", "him", "his", "hot", "hut", "hop", "hum", "hit", "hat", "has", "hug", "but", "big", "bet", "bad", "bad", "bed", "bud", "beg", "bug", "bun", "bus", "bat", "bit", "fit", "fin", "fun", "fig", "fan", "fat", "lap", "lot", "let", "leg", "lit"];

 var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0).sort(function () {
   return 0.5 - Math.random();
   }).slice(0, 12);

var tbl = document.createElement('table');
   tbl.className='tablestyle';
   var wordsPerRow = 2;


for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length; i += wordsPerRow) {
   var row = document.createElement('tr');

for (var j=i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++ j) {
    var word = shuffledWords[j];

    for (var k = 0; k < word.length; k++){
        var cell = document.createElement('td');


        cell.textContent = word[k];
        // IF FIREFOX USE cell.textContent = word[j]; INSTEAD
        row.appendChild(cell);
       }
   }
   tbl.appendChild(row);    
}

document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Comment: So if you set the width and height of the td's why does that not work?  What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: If I do the width and height of the td's it does work, but certain letters like M stretch the whole column. I have tried font size but it makes no difference either @jeschafe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you messed with the min-width, max-width, and letter-spacing settings?  Here I set it to 42px (just arbitary) and it sets all the columns the same.  i believe you might be able to use a combination of this to acheive what you want.  (I'm not sure if the width's should be dynamic either)  so that's something you can play with.  Here's just the modified demo.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e5BKq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

> I have fiddled around with the CSS but no luck...

This is exactly what CSS is for. Here's an example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/emahex) | [source](http://jsbin.com/emahex/edit)

CSS:

```css
#target td {
  width: 3em;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<table id="target">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>four</td>
      <td>five</td>
      <td>six</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

(The fact you're generating your content dynamically doesn't matter.)

Comment: @m0onio: Because you've told the browser to make **each cell** 372px wide, which it can't do in the available area, and so it ignores you and does its best to make things work. The selector `table, td` means "apply this styling to all `table` elements, and to all `td` elements." Contrast with `table td`, which means "apply this to all `td` elements that are within `table` elements".

Comment: what would you propose I do about it? @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @m0onio: Make the cells a reasonable size, and don't tell the browser to make both the table and its cells the same width, because that makes no sense (unless the table has only one cell per row). You have six cells there. You've told the browser each one should be 372px wide. So you've told it to put 2,232 pixels (six cells) inside a 372 pixel-wide table. Don't do that. :-) Separate out the styling to apply to the `table` from the styling to apply to the `td` elements. (Hint: If you have six cells and you want to have them fill the table, give each a width of 16.7%, unless you have borders.)